# CherryPy and flask logging using config file

Tags: logging, cherrypy, flask

When I have one flask app mounted under / running on cherrypy, is there a way to have the flask app logging be performed to nameOfFlaskApp.error.log and nameOfApp.access.log and as well have the cherrypy log go to its own access and error log?

Without having to make another python script just to steer the loggings this way...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When hosting a WSGI application you don't go through the full CherryPy engine stack and therefore you don't have access to some functionalities such as logging.

Here you should just wrap your application into a WSGI middleware that
provides what you need, look for instance at the **wsgilog** module

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsgilog/

Have a look at this code as well:
http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Logging-to-screen-with-a-WSGI-application-td1928526.html

Comment: Wow. I was struggling to figure out why my logging wasn't working. Thanks.

I did find out that you can configure CherryPy to make use of the WSGI logging by setting the `log.wsgi` directing in your config. (http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cplogging.html#cherrypy._cplogging.LogManager.wsgi)

Answer (score 0):

I stumble upon this awesome realtime event logging service:
https://github.com/dcramer/sentry

It's literally 3 lines of code and install two modules!